# Has there been a followup paper?

Tags: specific-reference

I am reading [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.94.084035)

> M. Christodoulou et al. *Planck-star tunneling-time: an astrophysically relevant observable from background free quantum gravity* Phys. Rev. D. **94** (2016) 084035

At the end they promise a followup paper to discuss the study of their final formula, but I cannot seem to find it.